# JS - How does this loop crash the browser?

Tags: javascript, loops, crash, infinite-loop

I wrote my first JavaScript code in Microsoft Edge's JS console:

```
var times = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < times; times++)
{
    console.log(times);
}
```

Soon after, it make the browser become unresponsive and crash.

Why and How?

Granted it is an infinite loop.
But how does storing the value of `times` and incrementing it continuosly crashes it.
Is holding the value of a few variables that taxing?

After all there are a million other calculations being performed continously in the computers like time and gui features of the system. They don't cause crashes.

I am definitely missing something about the actual internal workings that produce this crash.

**To summarize the question:**
How does above loop crash the browser?

Explanation of internal mechanism needed.

Comment: An infinite loop blocks all other execution on the thread. So, the browser, or tab might crash depending on what you're using to run it and how it wants to handle it.

Comment: Y u adding times at the end of the loop
add { i }

Comment: ... and `console.log(i)` unless you have a *very* specific reason in creating an infinite loop that way.

Comment: Simple answer: because Javascript is single-threaded, meaning nothing else can happen while that thread is busy with the loop, which it will be forever unless something kills it.

Comment: @Lennholm Please consider making this comment an answer as I am willing to accept this and there is no other satisfactory answer on this page.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
var times = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < times; i++)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You were incrementing the "wrong" variable.
By incrementing `times`, `i` will never "reach" it.

Comment: OP already knows the issue. They are asking why does this infinite loop crash the browser.

Comment: @iAmOren I am incrementing times intentionally. I am not interested in "fixing the crash". I want to know "how" and "why" it happens in the first place.

Comment: @MurtazaMagsi, Can you please elaborate how you implied your required answer from this answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think its because your variable `times` is incrementing by 1 infinitely and, at a time, it reaches a special number: the integer limit.
It's a big number that changes if you are on 32bits OS or 64bits OS and, when it tries to add 1 to the variable `times` and it reached the integer limit, the browser crashes because it's a bug from your processor and everyone has this bug. Since there is no time to wait between iteration, it takes only some seconds to reach this number, which is the number `2 147 483 647` on 32bits systems and `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`.

[image: screenshot from Microsoft's website]
See my screenshot for the source of the data (long int is 32bit int and llong int is 64bits int, and ulong and ullong ints is the space between the minimal int and the maximal int). My screenshot was taken from [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits?view=msvc-170).

By the way, maybe (or not) you have heard of the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), its due to the fact that the Unix Timestamp (the number of seconds elapsed since the 1st of January 1970) is gonna reach the 32bits integer limit and the time is gonna reset to the 1st of January 1970 but only on 32bits systems, that's why we are right now in a transition to 64bits CPUs, because this bug on 64bits CPUs in gonna happen on... Friday 11 April 2262.

[image: screenshot from an unix-timestamp converter]
[image: annother screenshot from an unix-timestamp converter]

Hope it helped, and to make a link with problem reported by other people ("JS is single-threaded so browser crashes") I think its true and that's also why is browser bugging before the `times` variable reach the integer limit.